# Self generated Public Keys do have the same beginning

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle, bitcoin, elliptic-curve

I'm trying to generate a "Secp256k1" keypair with java.

```
ECParameterSpec ecSpec = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("secp256k1");
KeyPairGenerator g = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDSA", "BC");
g.initialize(ecSpec, new SecureRandom());
KeyPair keyPair = g.generateKeyPair();

PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
PublicKey publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();

System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(privateKey.getEncoded()));

System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(publicKey.getEncoded()));
```

But if i look at the Outputs, my keypair always looks simmular.

Try 0:
Pubkey: MFYwEAYHKoZIzj0CAQYFK4EEAAoDQgAEx2WR3g1ytBdx8VJ+N121FFjn/YFbZ77ZumqVteTXAHnzN9fR+3NRD0EQ8kb+TnHvDMCtRR6a7GE8ckVVpajCrA==

Try 1:
Pubkey: MFYwEAYHKoZIzj0CAQYFK4EEAAoDQgAEpzA5+Zd8xtD7UH0IxlIyIGIFCjctvzGMqBKEpqDf09PLTGcp9UrDHOB/uWH9VGA+nJAUjnPtxSR+njuDZy4JZw==

Try 2:
Pubkey: MFYwEAYHKoZIzj0CAQYFK4EEAAoDQgAEbXclGh0T7jScfGfJNhAw6MnFI4AcpAytdd7TsrEykbOVGsT8xBla7x7uYdlBp3KNVQPG7E9X5Ajftd1dOyTjeA==

Try 3:
Pubkey: MFYwEAYHKoZIzj0CAQYFK4EEAAoDQgAEACJKf861/P4yhsJnPMitSWiLNrbvBEYdB/pndY0ScUWdKfIPhA3qbHLTzYPROA7wiGbj2oS7joxYzhrrWb0rwA==

"MFYwEAYHKoZIzj0CAQYFK4EEAAoDQgAE" the beginning is always the same, and it ends with "=="

Im sure there is something im missing. Does anybody knows why it always beginns with the same 32 characters?

Comment: This is probably the curve params that are embedded in the encoded key.

Comment: `==` is a base64 padding. Perfectly normal.

Comment: The prologue to every public key of the same type is the same, as it serves to identify the type. There is no problem here to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using `BouncyCastle` as the provider, your public key will be instance of `BCECPublicKey`. The `getEncoded` method of this class reuturns encoded `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` structure. This is defined in [`RFC5480`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5480) :

```
SubjectPublicKeyInfo  ::=  SEQUENCE  {
   algorithm         AlgorithmIdentifier,
   subjectPublicKey  BIT STRING
}
```

The first field of this structure is algorithm of type `AlgorithmIdentifier`. Since you do not change the algorithm for your keys - the bytes at the begining are the same (they designate the same algorithm) and this is expected behaviour.

Comment: Since the AlgId is the same _and_ the _length_ of the keys is the same (which is true for X9.62-format ECC, and also for RSA, but not for some other algorithms), the prefix of the DER encoding is constant. This is not only for BC; [all JCA public keys encode as X.509/PKIX SPKI](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/security/Key.html)